# How to get the environment variable in SessionCustomizer using eclipselink?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink, aspectj

I am trying to dynamically set the schema for my JPA entity objects using SessionCustomizer. I have the schema name defined in the properties file. I am trying to read from the environment object but the environment object is not available inside my class implementing SessionCustomizer as the class is invoked from eclipse link JAR file and its invoking by creating a new object instance. I am unable to autowire as spring is not aware of the new object as its instantiated outside the spring container.

```
public class SessionConfig implements SessionCustomizer {

    // holder for the spring environment
    private Environment environment;

    private static final String JDBC_SCHEMA = "JDBC_SCHEMA";

    /*
     * Constructor
     */
    public SessionConfig() {
        // nothing to do
    }

    /*
     * Getter for the environment variable
     */
    public Environment getEnvironment() {
        return this.environment;
    }

    /*
     * Setter for the environment variable
     */
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(Session session) throws Exception {
        // use this to dynamically change the schema 
        session.getLogin().setTableQualifier(environment.getProperty(JDBC_SCHEMA));
    }

}
```

I tried using AspectJ to get the environment object but its not going to the class.

```
@Aspect
@Configurable
public class SessionCustomizerAspect {

    // use the spring environment
    @Autowired
    private static Environment environment;

    /*
     * Constructor
     */
    public SessionCustomizerAspect() {
        // no implementation
    }

    /*
     * We need this implemented when we define an @Aspect as a @Component
     * 
     */
    public static SessionCustomizerAspect aspectOf() {
        return ApplicationContextHolder.getApplicationContext().getBean(SessionCustomizerAspect.class);
    }   

    /*
     * Intercept calls to the constructor at SessionConfig new
     */
    @Around("execution(com.foo.SessionConfig.new())")
    public static Object injectEnvironment(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, SessionConfig sessionConfig) throws Throwable {
        // this is required but continue on
        Object retVal = pjp.proceed(); 

        // set the autowired environment in to the sessionConfig 
        sessionConfig.setEnvironment(environment);
        return retVal;
    }

}
```

How can I get the environment object in SessionConfig class?